# Old Bit Coin Wallet Failing to Pass 180 Weeks

Tags: wallet, synchronization

I have an old laptop that I have bitcoin wallet on. I left the computer alone since early 2015 and when I try to sync the bitcoin wallet, the wallet gets stuck on 180 weeks. the bitcoin wallet sync process just eats way at hard drive space and stays at 180 weeks. I free up over 70 Gb and it still just just eats at hard drive space.

Comment: What version of Bitcoin Core?  Older versions may not be compatible with the current blockchain.  I would back up your wallet.dat file, upgrade the software, and try again.

Comment: Note that the blockchain today is about 184 GB, and you will need more than that for the chainstate index, etc.  So 70 GB will not suffice.  However, with newer software, you can enable pruning to reduce disk usage.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, backup your wallet.dat even if you are not going to do anything to the wallet.

I don't know if you are open to using other wallets, but you could recover your bitcoin by following these steps:

- Unlock your wallet
- Use the command `dumpprivkey "YOURADDRESS"` from the Bitcoin Core console
- Import the private keys on a lightweight wallet such as [Electrum](https://electrum.org/) (Warning: There was a scam message being shown in Electrum sometime ago)